# TTest in Excel across multiple columns

Tags: excel, statistics

I have 56 columns that are of different lengths. I want to be a series of TTests between all of them. I know that the syntax in Excel is TTest(array1, array2, tail, type). Is there a fast way to do this with labeling? I know that manually there are 1540 combinations. I really do not want to type that many formulas out in Excel. So there are 56 columns. The first position in each column is a label for what data is in that column.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution to your problem lays in the formula `=OFFSET`.
To display all solutions I wrote the numbers 1 to 56 (column number of first data set) in row 1 and 1 to 56 (column number of second data set) in column A and then you would only calculate the t-test for the lower half of this "cube".
This can be done with (here I just take always an array of length 100, because as far as I know empty cells will just be ignored by `TTEST`

```
=IF($A3<=B$1;"";TTEST(OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1;0;$A3-1;100);OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1;0;B$1-1;100);1;2))
```

I hope this helps.